# Can't delete a named range in the excel name manager that refers to a range in a deleted workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I deleted the worksheet over a year ago so I can't recover it, and don't need it anyway. I'm now trying to clean out names in the name manager that refer to ranges in the deleted worksheet.  However, the Edit and Delete buttons are greyed out. The invalid path shows in the RefersTo input bar. The Value column has #Ref!
I tried the following code to go through the names to find those with Value of #Ref! and delete them but it didn't delete those names.
...

```
 Sub DeleteAllREFRanges()
      Dim n As Name

      For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If InStr(n.Value, "#REF!") > 0 Then n.Delete
      Next n

    End Sub
```

...

Comment: Shot in the dark, try changing `n.Value` to `n.RefersTo` and run that macro again.

Comment: As a general case in VBA debugging - write `Debug.Print n.Value` before the `If line`, to see what are you getting there. It could be that the `Activeworkbook` is something else or anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks dwirony and Vityata for the suggestions. All the names I wanted to delete were scoped to a specific worksheet in the deleted workbook. By using Debug I saw that n.Name returned the name in the format worksheet!name, for example, DonorSearch!CreativeServices, while n.Value and n.RefersTo both returned the full path the to the range in the deleted worksheet. So I verified that Instr(n.name, "Donor") returned 1 when n.name included the word Donor. And so the following macro removed all the names scoped to that deleted workbook (and worksheet) from the current workbook

```
...
Sub DeleteAllREFRanges()
  Dim n As Name

  For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(n.Name, "Donor") > 0 Then n.Delete
  Next n

End Sub
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was using to delete the named ranges with Errors. Make sure it works, then uncomment the `nName.Delete`. If you have some ideas for improvement, make a [Pull Request here](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/NamedRanges.vb).

```
Public Sub RemoveNamedRangesWithErrors()

    Dim nName                   As Name
    Dim strNameReserved         As String

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each nName In Names
        Debug.Print nName.RefersTo
        If Left(nName.RefersTo, 2) = "=#" Then
            Debug.Print nName.RefersTo
            'nName.Delete
        End If
    Next nName

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```